# Downgrading JodaTime 1.6 to 1.2

Tags: java, jodatime, backwards-compatibility

I have some code written in JodaTime 1.6 which I need to be compatible with JodaTime 1.2. In my code i am using Month and Day etc.

I would like to know if it would be possible to make this code compatible with JodaTime 1.2

```
cal.add(
   Calendar.MONTH, 
   Months.monthsBetween(
      new DateTime(referenceDate.getTime()), 
      new DateTime(startDate.getTime())
   ).getMonths() + numberOfMonths);
```

Is this feasible?

Also upgrading to 1.6 is not an option at this point in the project.